# Using and Maintaining IGroupedObservable

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

In my Rx code, I'm using GroupBy to create an `IObservable<IGroupedObservable<T>>`. From there I am looking to perform some transformations on the IGroupedObservable, while maintaining knowledge of the group (Key).

For example,

```
IObservable<IGroupedObservable<T>> CreateGroup(this IObservable<T> obs)
{
    return obs.GroupBy(o => o.Something);
}

IGroupedObservable<A> Foo(this IGroupedObservable<T> obs)
{
    return obs.Select(o => new A(o));
}

IGroupedObservable<B> Bar(this IGroupedObservable<A> obs)
{
    return obs.Select(o => new B(o));
}

IObservable<IGroupedObservable<B>> stillGrouped = initialObservable.CreateGroup().Select(grouped => grouped.Foo().Bar());
```

Of course I can't do this, because the `Select()` in Foo loses the IGroupedObservable-ness.

Has anyone seen any solutions to this?

EDIT **TLDR** I'm trying to compose operations that depend on an observable already being grouped, and I'd like the type system to enforce this for me. I suppose I could make these operations take the group Key, and perform a Where on that Key up front, but that's messier and slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm.

One brute force way is to replicate the observable methods you need.  Something like this:

```
private class GroupedObservable<TKey, TElement> : IGroupedObservable<TKey, TElement>
{
    private readonly IObservable<TElement> _o;
    private readonly TKey _k;

    public TKey Key { get { return _k } }

    public GroupedObservable(TKey key, IObservable<TElement> o)
    {
        _key = key;
        _o = ;
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<TElement> observer) { return _o.Subscribe(observer); }
}

public static IGroupedObservable<TKey, TResult> Select<TKey, TSource, TResult>(this IGroupedObservable<TKey, TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
{
    return new GroupedObservable<TKey, TResult>(source.Key, ((IObservable<TSource>)source).Select(selector));
}
```

Over time you'll build up a library of the methods you need.

Another simpler way is to just use `Select` to transform your `IGroupedObservable<TKey, TElement>` into `IObservable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TElement>>`:

```
public static IObservable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> ToKV<TKey, TValue>(this IGroupedObservable<TKey, TValue> g)
{
    return g.Select(v => new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(g.Key, v));
}

initialObservable.CreateGroup().Select(group => group.ToKV());
```

Comment: Yeah, that first option is probably what I'll go with. I was hoping [rxx](http://rxx.codeplex.com/) or some other library would've made those extensions :(.